# Why Outlook doesn't support background images and other HTML and CSS properties?

Tags: outlook

I think a lot of Web Designers and Developers already asked this question. Thank you Microsoft to restrict a very popular sofware. You make our life miserable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no conspiracy here. HTML in Outlook is created and displayed by Word, not IE. There are quite a few things it does not support.

If you really want MS to fix Outlook behavior, you'd be better off opening a support case with Microsoft. If the company you work for owns a few thousand licenses of MS Office, that will help speed things up a bit :-)

There is no reason to preach to the choir here; everybody will agree with you, but that won't change a thing.